# jQuery set select to select none

Tags: jquery

Below is my jQuery. Every time the `<select>` changes value, it shows another `<select>` with the same value with the `<option>`.

```js
$('#mode').on('change', function () {
    var value = $("#mode option:selected").val();
    $('.hide').slideUp('fast');
    $('#' + value).show('slow');
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
    <label class="control-label">Mode</label>
    <select class="input-large m-wrap" name="mode" id="mode" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="general">General Knowledge</option>
        <option value="preparatory">Preparatory Exam</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- MODULES -->
<div class=" hide" id="general">
    <br>
    <label class="control-label">Module</label>
    <select class="input-large m-wrap" name="module" id="sub">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Module 1">Module 1</option>
        <option value="Module 2">Module 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- A1 to Asomething -->
<div class=" hide" id="preparatory">
    <br>
    <label class="control-label">Exam</label>
    <select class="input-large m-wrap" name="exam" id="sub">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="A1">A1</option>
        <option value="A2">A2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The problem is when I've already selected an option in module but then decided to change to exam instead. The option selected in the module stays.

How can I set the value of the now hidden select to none? I've added `id="sub"` to the two `<select>`s to set the value to `""` using the following line `$('#sub').val() = "";` but it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: I've tried to set the `id="sub"` to `id="sub1"` and `id="sub2"` then used

```
$('#sub1').val() = "";
$('#sub2').val() = "";
```

But still no luck.

Comment: Identifiers(ID) in HTML must be unique

Comment: Even if the purpose is to target both at the same time?

Comment: That's what `class` are for : Target multiples element at the same time.

Comment: Yes, You can use a css class the you can use class selector i.e. `$('.yourClass')`

Comment: Yes; but you could use a custom class instead of using the `id` more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `find()` the `select` element within the `.hide` and set its `val()`. Try this:

```
$('.hide').slideUp('fast').find('select').val('');
```

Also note that you have duplicate `id` attributes set on different elements - this is invalid as `id` must be unique within the scope of a page.

Working snippet:

```js
$('#mode').on('change', function () {
    var value = $("#mode option:selected").val();
    $('.hide').slideUp('fast').find('select').val('');
    $('#' + value).show('slow');
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
    <label class="control-label">Mode</label>
    <select class="input-large m-wrap" name="mode" id="mode" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="general">General Knowledge</option>
        <option value="preparatory">Preparatory Exam</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- MODULES -->
<div class=" hide" id="general">
    <br>
    <label class="control-label">Module</label>
    <select class="input-large m-wrap" name="module" id="sub">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Module 1">Module 1</option>
        <option value="Module 2">Module 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- A1 to Asomething -->
<div class=" hide" id="preparatory">
    <br>
    <label class="control-label">Exam</label>
    <select class="input-large m-wrap" name="exam" id="sub">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="A1">A1</option>
        <option value="A2">A2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. It works now. Thank you. Never thought of doing it that way. Will select as answer after the time duration thing.